# SQL Server delete records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I have two tables `computers`, and `softwareinstalls`.

Computers primary key is computerid, softwareinstalls has three fields (installid, computerid, and lastmodifieddate).

Software installs computerid joined with computers.computerid.

I'm trying to delete all softwareinstalls on a computer that have a last modified date more than 1 day before the max for that computer, so...

software installs table

```
install  computerid  lastmodifieddate
1        1           01-16-13
2        1           01-16-13
3        1           01-14-13
4        2           01-12-13
5        2           01-10-13
```

would delete records 3 and 5.  what would be the query in sql server?

Comment: what version of Sql Server are you running? The query will be easier if you have 2005+ as you can use Partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join on delete statements. Use `LEFT JOIN` on this.

```
DELETE  a
FROM    softwareinstalls a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT computerID, max(lastmodifieddate) max_date
            FROM softwareinstalls
            GROUP BY computerID
        ) b ON a.computerID = b.computerID AND
                a.lastmodifieddate = b.max_date
WHERE   b.computerID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df16b/2)

For better performance, add an index on columns `computerID` and `lastmodifieddate`.